# What happens when a C++ thrift (NonBlocking) server loses a connection?

Tags: c++, apache, thrift

I am failing to find any examples of thrift exception/error handling.  How can I programatically catch the scenario where a server loses a connection to it's assigned port, and either log or restart the server, as desired by my application?

Comment: Define 'loses a connection to its assigned port'.

Comment: When the port no longer shows any activity associated with the server that had previously been running on it, and new connections cannot be made, becuase the server is down